# How do I stop the command prompt window from appearing every time I run the program in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project in Visual Studio, and every time I compile and run the project, the command prompt window pops up.

I know I have managed to disable that in previous projects by switching the subsystem from `CONSOLE` to `WINDOWS` but when I do that now I have to declare the `main` function as `WinMain`. I swear I didn't have to do that in one of my older projects. When I go into that old project, the `Subsystem` in `Linker` is set to `WINDOWS`, but the `main` function is just called `main`.

How did I manage to do that? I really want to recreate it, but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: You can't use a `main()` entry point for a `Windows` program, just as you can't use a `WinMain()` entry point for a `Console` program. Those combinations are simply not compatible.  `WinMain` is compatible with `Windows` programs, and `main()` is compatible with `Console` programs.  But, that being said, you are probably looking for the [`/ENTRY` linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Do you have a console application or is this a GUI application?

Comment: Can't you just put your code in `WinMain`? I mean - what is the problem?

Comment: Is this related to Qt? If so you use int main() in a GUI application and the WINDOWS subsystem but link to qtmain.lib

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yup, `/ENTRY` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!